# Dial up HSF usb Conexant modem linux driver for ARM architecture

Tags: raspbian, driver, internet, arm

Hello I've being trying to install my usb HSF Conexant dial up modem to my Raspberry PI 2 B which is running Raspbian OS. I checked a company named Linuxant that makes these kind of drivers but apparently they only support x86 CPU architecture. Are there dial up HSF Linux generic drivers for ARM architecture? I tried to use Debian drivers but as they were for x86 they didn't work with ARM and I got the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing hsfmodem_7.80.02.06oem_i386.deb (--install):
package architecture (i386) does not match system (armhf)
Errors were encountered while processing:
hsfmodem_7.80.02.06oem_i386.deb
```

This dial up modem is the only possible way I have to connect to the Internet (I'm Cuban). Right now I'm connecting my PC to the Internet with this dial up modem, making a hotspot and sending the internet to the Raspberry through wifi but this severely decreases the speed.

Recently I have found the following explanation to the process of installing the driver, but I don't understand step 3, does it mean that I can rebuild the driver for ARM? How do I do it?

METHOD B: DEBIAN PACKAGE (*.deb)
If you have obtained the driver package in DEBIAN format:

1. install the package with `dpkg -i hsfmodem_{version}_{arch}.deb`, if apt-get or some other tool hasn't already done it for you.
2. if necessary, run `hsfconfig` to complete the installation, or to change your modem's configuration.
3. If you need to rebuild the Debian generic package from source, you can get the TAR package, and from the top directory run: `make debdist`. A pre-compiled DEB package for the currently running kernel can be built using `make debprecomp` instead.

Comment: Yikes -- you may be out of luck with this.  The only thing I can suggest is that the source for the (long unmaintained) Linuxant driver is available; although it's ostensibly tagged as architecture specific you could try compiling it on the pi anyway.

Comment: And it targets ancient (2.x?) Linux kernels IIRC - I have more than one laptop and I've never had any joy with their HSF modems - I just wanted one to capture Caller ID on incoming calls but that was a non-starter...

Comment: As a matter of fact I tried to compile it, that's how I realized I needed the ARM version. I will update my question with the output error

Comment: I updated the question with the error message and some extra info I found

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed how old this is. But, in the unlikely event someone else needs this answered - linuxant.com provides a source package as well, called      hsfmodem-7.80.02.06oem.tar.gz. With a little tweaking you can get it to compile on a Raspberry Pi 3 - I haven't tried it on a 2B. I did have to make a link to the kernel headers - it was looking in the wrong place - or you could probably adjust the makefile.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.24-v7+/ /usr/src/kernel-headers-4.9.24-v7+
```

It compiled fine after that.

Comment: What other things did you have to do? I'm getting issues running hsfconfig ... WARNING: missing file /lib/modules/4.14.98-v7+/build/include/linux/version.h
- The only difference is that I'm using linux 4.14.98-v7+ since I'm in 2019, not 2017 ;-)